# Как скрыть cmd в lua? Как вывести данные команды из ShellExecute?

Tags: cmd, lua

Я использую io.popen для обновления файлов в директории, но при вызове открывается консоль, что сильно мешает при работе с lua в полном экране. В данный момент я пытаюсь получить данные от команды dir /a-d через ShellExecute. Хотелось бы узнать, как скрыть консоль, или вывести информацию о файлах в директории через ShellExecute.

Comment: ипсользуйте библиотеку "Lua file system" -  `require('lfs')`

Comment: ShellExecute 'dir path > file'
f = io.open( file, 'r' )
a = f:read('*a')
f:close()

Comment: или через `os.execute ('dir /a-d > file1.tmp' )`